# Discrepancy in switch statement results

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
function skyCoverage( $metarClouds ) {

    foreach( $metarClouds[0] as $cloudReport ) {
        $coverageCode = substr( $cloudReport, 0, 3 );

        // I check $coverageCode here, and it is indeed "CLR"

            switch( $coverageCode ) {
                case "CLR":
                    $cloudCoverage = 0;
                    break;
                case "FEW":
                    $cloudCoverage = 1/8;
                    break;
                case "SCT":
                    $cloudCoverage = 3/8;
                    break;
                case "BKN":
                    $cloudCoverage = 5/8;
                    break;
                case "OVC":
                    $cloudCoverage = 8/8;
                    break;
            }
    $skyCoverage = $skyCoverage + $cloudCoverage;
    }

// I check $skyCoverage here, and it is indeed 0

    switch ( $skyCoverage ) {
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 1.00 ):
                $skyCondition = "Overcast";
                // I do an echo $skyCoverage; here, and it actually spits out 0 still, even though it obviously shouldn't do anything at all
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 0.75 ):
                $skyCondition = "Cloudy";
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 0.625 ):
                $skyCondition = "Mostly Cloudy";
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 0.5 ):
                $skyCondition = "Scattered Clouds";
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 0.375 ):
                $skyCondition = "Partly Cloudy";
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage >= 0.125 ):
                $skyCondition = "Mostly Clear";
                break;
        case ( $skyCoverage < 0.125 ):
                $skyCondition = "Clear";
                break;
    }

// $skyCoverage is still zero here

return $skyCondition;
// Somehow $skyCondition is "Overcast" with $skyCoverage = 0
```

}

Typically, more than one cloud layer is observed and, therefore, each `$cloudCoverage` at the layer is added onto the other while looping through `$metarClouds[0]`. However, if there is no cloud layer (clear, or "CLR"), then it should register as 0. And it does. However, the code somehow returns "Overcast".

I've checked both switch statements to ensure that "CLR" is being passed when I expect it is, and that `$cloudCoverage` is equating to zero when I expect. It is, every time. And, `$skyCoverage` still registers as zero just before the return.

I have tried setting `$cloudCoverage` to 1-1, 0/1, 0.0, or some other method to ensure that PHP isn't somehow treating it as null and ... somehow ... processing it incorrectly. If I rewrite so that `$cloudCoverage = 0.01` and pass CLR through the first switch, everything comes through the second switch correctly: Clear. I've also tried setting the last case to `case 0:` etc., but still have the same erroneous result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at how

```
switch ( $skyCoverage ) {
  case ( $skyCoverage >= 1.00 ):
```

is evaluated. First let's substitute $skyCover by 0

```
switch ( 0 ) {
  case ( 0 >= 1.00 ):
```

Now evaluate the case-condition

```
switch ( 0 ) {
  case ( false ):
```

And since (bool)0===false, it's a match
(see http://docs.php.net/language.types.boolean#language.types.boolean.casting).
As pygorex1 said that's not the way `switch/case` works. You want an

```
if (...) {
}
else if (...) {
}
else {
}
```

instead.

(edit: using the "identical operator" === in "(bool)0===false" isn't a good explanation. switch/case performs a [loose comparison](http://docs.php.net/types.comparisons#types.comparisions-loose), i.e it allows [type juggling](http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling), like in 0==false which evaluates to TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `switch` statements work:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Edit: take this code snippet:

```
switch ( $skyCoverage ) {
    case ( $skyCoverage >= 1.00 ):
            $skyCondition = "Overcast";
```

When `$skyCoverage` is `0` the statement `$skyCoverage >= 1.00` will evaluate to false. So, the `case ( $skyCoverage >= 1.00 )` statement is evaluated as this: `case ( false )` and since `0 == false` the end result will be `Overcast`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that:

```
( $skyCoverage >= 1.00 )
```

evaluates to false or 0 and as you're comparing it with $skyCoverage (0), the first one is automatically selected.